# Django Rest API pagination populate same entry in several page

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I created an API with pagination function in it, Its sort of working, but the only weird thing is let say i declared only 10 entry will be display in 1 page, for several pages (e.g: 1-3) it populate the same entry and less than 10 entry but when I open the 4th page, it populate the next entry also less than 10 and then same thing happen until I open to the 8th page, can anyone tell me why this bug is happening.

Heres my API :

```
class ModelAFilterAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, project_id, search_type="", format=None):
        print(search_type)
        search_type_list_split = search_type.split('_')
        search_type_list = list(map(int, search_type_list_split))
        model_object = ModelA.objects.filter(project=project_id, id__in=search_type_list)
        paginator = Paginator(model_object, 10)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            model_object = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            model_object = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            model_object = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        serializer = ModelASerializer(model_object, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination


    class FilterApiPagination(PageNumberPagination):
        '''Get Boards Pagination'''
        page_size = 20

        def get_paginated_response(self, data):
            return Response(OrderedDict([
                ('next', self.get_next_link()),
                ('previous', self.get_previous_link()),
                ('results', data)
            ]))

    class ModelAFilterAPI(generics.ListAPIView):
          serializer_class = ModelASerializer
          pagination_class = FilterApiPagination
        def get(self, request, project_id, search_type="", format=None):
            print(search_type)
            search_type_list_split = search_type.split('_')
            search_type_list = list(map(int, search_type_list_split))
            model_object = ModelA.objects.filter(project=project_id, id__in=search_type_list)
        return Response({'data': model_object})
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, this looks valid, its throwing me a few error now, I'm working on it, I'll notify you again, once solve the issue, thanks a lot Suresh!